# Fetch id's of the rows from a boundary table where, the data is overlapping or intersecting given lat long with radius

Tags: mysql, sql, geometry

My question: I want to fetch all rows from the table given lat long and radius and the rows whose boundary (lat longs) are enclosed/intersecting within the given radius from that lat long.

The core concept behind this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding
(reverse geocoding)

- the google maps API will be able to give solve this, but I need to do this with the data I have in my DB.

Table name: boundary

Columns: id, boundary

Column type: id -> varchar(255), boundary -> geometry

The query I used:

```
SELECT *
FROM boundary
WHERE ST_Distance(boundary, POINT(12.929961819992359, 77.60920439843274)) / 1000 <= 1;
```

The response I get: OK (in MySQL workbench)

Seeking help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify geographic spatial reference systems (SRS) of your data. MySql default SRID is 0 which is not suitable for geographic points. For example

```
create table g (
  id int,
  p geometry
);

insert g 
  values
    row(1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (39 49)', 4326)),
    row(2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (39 51)', 4326)),
    row(3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (41 51)', 4326)),
    row(4, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (41 49)', 4326));

select id, ST_Distance(p, ST_PointFromText('POINT (40 50)', 4326)) d
from g;
```

Returns

```
id  d
1   140443.45807500975
2   140443.45807500975
3   139699.30401230097
4   139699.30401230097
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v6PC6pf2)

Comment: the above query returns me distance and IDs (in my case I'm getting the first 10 rows in my table i.e what ever I'm keeping the limit).
I need the query to be fetching id's where in we give lat long and radius and the data in boundary column should enlcose with in this radius

Comment: @Abhilash, What is SRID of the `boundary` column? Use the same  in your point constructor and make it valid WKT or WKB depending on what is your source of lat long coords. Edit the question and provide your sample data if more help is needed.

Comment: SRID of the column in my DB is 0, the source of my lat long radius is a frontend application sent via API and I had to make SQL query with the received details

Comment: @Abhilash, "SRID of the column in my DB is 0" this is the problem. You haven't told the system your data are geographic lot/lan coords and it treats them as X Y on a plane